# NMake .PHONY analogue

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have both a target `test` in my Makefile and a directory called `test` in my project. In GNU Make I can declare it to be phony like this:

```
.PHONY: all compile test clean docs static
```

Is it possible to do the same in NMake? According to http://www.bell-labs.com/project/nmake/tutorial/s6.html, I need to do

```
test: .VIRTUAL
```

but it doesn't work:

```
F:\SomePath>nmake test /f msvc.mk

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '.VIRTUAL'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/description-blocks#pseudotargets

> Pseudotargets
>
> A pseudotarget is a label used in place of a filename in a dependency line. It is interpreted as a file that does not exist, and so is out-of-date. NMAKE assumes a pseudotarget's timestamp is the most recent of all its dependents. If it has no dependents, the current time is assumed. If a pseudotarget is used as a target, its commands are always executed. A pseudotarget used as a dependent must also appear as a target in another dependency. However, that dependency does not need to have a commands block.
>
> Pseudotarget names follow the filename syntax rules for targets. However, if the name does not have an extension (that is, does not contain a period), it can exceed the 8-character limit for filenames and can be up to 256 characters long.

If i understand it correctly you don't have a .PHONY in nmake (Microsoft's, there are many nmake flavors out there). And the link you posted states that on top:

> Tutorial: A Little Help With **Alcatel-Lucent nmake**

Maybe you could call one test and the other one tests?

Comment: I had in fact found this page, but assumed there should still be a way to do it, just not linked :) Perhaps not.

Answer (score 9):

For those who are seeking for a way around this absent .PHONY in nmake:

You may introduce a target which would definitely be a pseudotarget (i.e. choose a name not matching any of the existing files/directories) and make it a dependent of what you mean to be a .PHONY. E.g.:

```
test: .phony
        dir /b

.phony:
```

And here's the output:

```
D:\Temp\nmake-phony>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        dir /b
Makefile
test
```